# How to display PDF page in a web page and allow drawing of rectanges on it

Tags: javascript, asp.net, flash, pdf

I need some way of displaying a PDF page in a web page and then be able to draw boxes over the top of the image which I can then record the position in my own table.

My thoughts initially are:

1) When choosing the PDF convert the PDF to an image or html.

2) How to then draw rectanges with the mouse over the image.

I have an idea of how to do the first part but not the 2nd.

Any ideas?

Comment: You will need to use an image as anything else will need a plugin and be outside of the pages' javascript reach. For the second part of the question: google javascript rubber band effect.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I will take a look at the rubber band effect.